# Java getting bytes of clipboard

Tags: java, string, byte, clipboard

So I want to get the actual bytes of the user's clipboard. I can't find a way of doing this, all I find is how to get the clipboard as a String.

To get the clipboard as a String, I'd have to do something like this:

```
String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: convert String to bytes then using `data.getBytes()`;

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the String representation of the clipboard, you can get the bytes via [String#getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29).

```
byte[] clipboardBytes = clipboardString.getBytes();
```